# Disable UIButton after UITextField is no longer hidden?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a simple task but I don't seem to be able to figure it out. I have a `UIViewController` that has 5 `UITextFields`. 2 of those `UITextFields` are always visible. The other 3 are being shown when the user hits a `UIButton`.  My goal is to disable the `UIButton` so it's obvious to the user that they cannot "add" more `UITextFields` after ALL of the `UITextFields` are visible. I tried to do this:

```
@IBAction func addTextFieldPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden, !forthChoiceTextField.isHidden, !fifthChoiceTextField.isHidden {
        addTextFieldButton.isEnabled = false
    }
        if thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        else if forthChoiceTextField.isHidden {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.forthChoiceTextField.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.fifthChoiceTextField.isHidden = false

        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. You're able to add the `UITextFields`. There's also a `UIButton` that allows the user to remove the 3 added `UITextField`. So, I have to make sure that if all of the text fields are shown, the `UIButton` responsible for adding more `UITextFields` would be disabled, but if any of the `UITextFields` is removed (`.isHidden = true`), the button should be enabled once again.

**UPDATE:** This is the code that runs after the user hits the "hide" button and it basically hides either 3rd, 4th or 5th `UITextField`

```
@objc func hideTextField(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let  field = sender.superview?.superview as? UITextField, !field.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            field.text = ""
            field.isHidden = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing else condition.

```
@IBAction func addTextFieldPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden, !forthChoiceTextField.isHidden, !fifthChoiceTextField.isHidden {
        addTextFieldButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    else{
        addTextFieldButton.isEnabled = true
    }
    if thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    else if forthChoiceTextField.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.forthChoiceTextField.isHidden = false
        }
    }
    else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.fifthChoiceTextField.isHidden = false

    }
  }
}
```

Update (try adding this to enable the button)

```
@objc func hideTextField(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let  field = sender.superview?.superview as? UITextField, !field.isHidden {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            field.text = ""
            field.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    if !thirdChoiceTextField.isHidden, !forthChoiceTextField.isHidden, !fifthChoiceTextField.isHidden {
        addTextFieldButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    else{
        addTextFieldButton.isEnabled = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't make any difference.

Comment: That's exactly what I did right before I saw your reply. This solved the issue. Thank you.